# How To Change Bool Datatype Based on Consecutive Values in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

I have a Pandas dataframe, *df*, with monthly counts of crime tyes. I have various other columns as well. For example, df looks like:

| ID | Year_Month | Total | Valid or Missing | Median_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AL0010000 | 1991-01 | 2572 | True | 815 |
| AL0010000 | 1991-02 | 4217 | True | 815 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| WVWSP9800 | 2018-11 | 0 | False | 0 |
| WVWSP9800 | 2018-12 | 0 | False | 0 |

I want to do the following:

For any 4 consecutive months of Total value 0 (for same ID), I want to change the Valid or Missing value to False IF it is True. If the Valid or Missing value is already False, I want to keep it False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution

```
# Is total zero?
m = df['Total'] == 0

# Counter to identify different blocks 
# of consecutive rows having zeros 
b = (~m).cumsum()[m]

# Group by ID and blocks and check the
# size of group if its greater than 4
is_more_than_4_zeros = df.groupby(['ID', b])['ID'].transform('size') >= 4

# Invert the boolean values where there are more than 4 zeros
df['Valid or Missing'] *= ~is_more_than_4_zeros
```

Comment: Will this run the risk of making previous False values True? Doesn't this assume that all four 'valid or missing' values are True.

Comment: @TheMaffGuy It will not since we are using a boolean multiplication in the final statement so it will only affect the rows which have more than 4 consecutive zeros.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use a `groupby.rolling`:

```
# number of zeros
N = 4

# True is there is N consecutive 0
m = df['Total'].eq(0).groupby(df['ID']).rolling(N).sum().eq(N).values

# update to False
# NB. not need to check if it is already False
# if really you want to:
# m = m & ~df['Valid   or  Missing']
df.loc[m, 'Valid or Missing'] = False
```

Example output:

```
          ID Year_Month  Total  Valid or Missing  Median_Count
0  AL0010000    1991-01   2572              True           815
1  AL0010000    1991-02   4217              True           815
2  AL0010000    1991-03   4217              True           815
3  AL0010000    1991-04   4217              True           815
4  WVWSP9800    2018-11      0             False             0
5  WVWSP9800    2018-12      0             False             0
6  WVWSP9800    2019-01      0             False             0
7  WVWSP9800    2019-01      0              True             0
```

Used input:

```
          ID Year_Month  Total  Valid or Missing  Median_Count
0  AL0010000    1991-01   2572              True           815
1  AL0010000    1991-02   4217              True           815
2  AL0010000    1991-03   4217              True           815
3  AL0010000    1991-04   4217              True           815
4  WVWSP9800    2018-11      0             False             0
5  WVWSP9800    2018-12      0             False             0
6  WVWSP9800    2019-01      0             False             0
7  WVWSP9800    2019-01      0             False             0
```